# How to inspect a refresh token obtained from Azure in a code grant flow?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, refresh-token

I successfully implemented the code grant flow against Azure AAD according to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code)
Now I want to fiddle with the expiration of the refresh token I obtain.

The default expiration is 90 days and I want to lower it to 7. I want to verify that I succeeded without having to wait 7 days. The expriation of the refresh token is not returned in the API and 
I am unable to decode it as a JWT token (*is* it even a JWT?).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use [New-AzureADPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadpolicy?view=azureadps-2.0-preview) or [Microsoft Graph API Create Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/policy-post?view=graph-rest-beta) to set the lifetime of the refresh token.

Then you could use [Microsoft Graph API Get Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/policy-get?view=graph-rest-beta&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0) to see details of the the policy.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies
```

In the response you will see the `MaxInactiveTime` property which is the lifetime of the refresh token.

Comment: Thanks. I can inspect the policy but what I want is to see whether the policy took effect by observing the _actual_ expiration of the token.

Comment: @Vitaliy If you want to know if the policy takes effect, you can set a shorter time, say 20 minutes. If you think it's not useful, the only way is to wait 7 days.